# "SAML2Service Unavailable" error on Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, saml

I am trying to publish metadata for my SAML service provider in Weblogic 10.3.4. I am getting an error "SAML2Service Unavailable". Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Restarting the server

Comment: I had already tried it - did not work.

Comment: When you say publish metadata do you mean like the second to last step in this tutorial? http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/09/sso-with-weblogic-1031-and-saml2.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to resolve this by tracing this problem to another problem with the keys. Once I set the field "Use JSSE SSL" (in server's SSL advanced settings) to "checked", the problem went away.